# Interpretation of learning curve (training & validation)

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, cross-entropy

I know what a learning curve representative of an "ideal" overfitting looks like. However, I am not 100% sure how to interpret the learning curve shown below. Why does the model sometimes seem to "slip" ?

It is a small experiment of a binary classification problem with slightly imbalanced classes (2:1 ratio) which was implemented in keras. The loss is calculated as binary crossentropy. I accounted for the imbalance by weighing one class more as described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras).

P.s.: Not exactly sure whether this post belongs here or rather on data science stackexchange...

[image: Learning Curve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your validation data is separate from your training data and you have enough samples in both sets, I can see **no sign of overfitting** in these curves.

However it is possible to overfit on the validation set too, if you train your model over and over again to find the best hyper-parameters. Your safest bet would be testing the generalization of your model on a separate **hold-out test set** (besides the validation set).

The *slip* you refer to is sometimes an indication of a small number of samples. For example if you have 9 samples in your validation set, missing one would result in a steep drop. This does not seem to be the case, however, judging by the small shifts in some epochs. Another explanation could be that you have a **small number of samples in one of the under-represented classes**, which would be weighted by a large class weight. If that were the case, the effect of missing one of those samples would be **magnified by the large class weight**.

In any case you should evaluate on a test set on more metrics that just the accuracy. I'd recommend computing a **confusion matrix** which would give you a clear view of how your model performs for each class.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply: Your comment concerning small number of samples brought me the to the root cause: Due to a typo in the code, I used about 20% of the TRAINING data for validation, not any new data. Since I was using a generator, it was always a different 20% fraction of the training data (unshuffled). So I guess the "slips" occured at rather regular intervals when that fraction of the training data was grabbed that was not well represented by the model. (training data was about ~10000 images for a binary problem)